# How to filter columns in SAS

Tags: sas

Suppose you have a data set such as the following:

```
FSA1 SSA1 SBW1
1     2    3
```

Is there a way in a data step to filter columns that do not contain 'SA'? I don't want to use a drop or a keep statement as the real dataset has hundreds of variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
proc sql;
   select name into: dropnames
   separated by " "
   from dictionary.columns 
   where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CLASS' 
   having name contains 'He';
   quit;

   data class;
   set sashelp.class;
   drop &dropnames;
   run;
```

Comment: This is how you do what is asked.  The data step decides which columns are dropped/kept from both the input and output at compile time.  Once it is compiled, you cannot alter those columns at run time.

Comment: When I put my libname= 'WORK' and memname='mydata' the macro variable dropnames cannot be resolved

Comment: insert:  separated by ' ' after dropnames

Comment: The lib name, memname, and name parameters are also case sensitive. Open up sashelp.vtable to verify your data visually. You can also wrap those in upper/lower functions to make sure things resolve the way you expect.

Comment: When I type: proc sql;
   select name into: dropnames separated by ' '  from dictionary.columns where libname='Work' and memname='Mydata' having name contains 'SA';
   quit;

   %Put &dropnames;
I still get this warning: WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference DROPNAMES not resolved.

Comment: That means that nothing was returned in your query.  try `upcase(name) contains 'SA'`.  Also upcase() LIBNAME and MEMNAME.

Comment: `where libname='WORK' and memname='MYDATA'` - as Reeza said, they're case-sensitive, and SASHELP.VTABLE returns lib & memnames in upper-case.

Comment: Not *always* upper case, actually, but most of the time.